# Using NodaTime how do I compare the local time now to a fixed time?

Tags: c#, .net, time, nodatime

I want to be able to compare the current local time in C# using NodaTime to a fixed local time during the day. I do not need to worry about time zones or daylight savings, I just need to do the comparison with the local system time. So far I have this code...

```
IClock clock = SystemClock.Instance;
Instant instant = clock.Now;
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(timeZone);
var timeNow = zonedDateTime.ToString("HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int tst = timeNow.CompareTo(new LocalTime(11, 00));
if (tst < 0)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Time is before 11am.");
}
```

I get an error but as I am relatively new to C# and NodTime would appreciate some pointers where I am going wrong.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @Nikita the error I had was unrelated, just a C# noob issue which is now corrected. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the local system time, you *do* need to worry about the time zone. You can use:

```
var clock = SystemClock.Instance; // Or inject it, preferrably
// Note that this *could* throw an exception. You could use
// DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault() to use the Windows
// time zone database.
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
var now = clock.Now.InZone(zone);

if (now.TimeOfDay < new LocalTime(11, 0))
{
    ...
}
```

In Noda Time 2.0, this is made somewhat simpler using `ZonedClock`:

```
var zonedClock = SystemClock.Instance.InTzdbSystemDefaultZone();
if (zonedClock.GetCurrentTimeOfDay() < new LocalTime(11, 0))
{
    ...
}
```

For "earlier than 11 o'clock" you could always use `if (time.Hour < 11)` of course, but using a `LocalTime` is more general.

Comment: Thanks Jon, works a treat, I had to use the Windows time zone database variant to get it working, what's the deal with making `DateTimeProviders` available to use?

Comment: @Crispy: What do you mean? What went wrong when you used DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb?

Comment: I get the error `The name 'DateTimeProviders' does not exist in the current context`. Possibly my C# inexperience showing...

Comment: @CrispyBeef: Ah - that was just a typo for `DateTimeZoneProviders`. Fixed.